# database for scientific calculation

Tags: sql, database

I need to include a database in a C# project with a lot of data.
This database should be free even in a commercial use.

What database should I use?

[EDIT]

I would like to know what database are to be avoided.
When I say "a lot", it's for scientific calculation so it will be huge data.

Comment: Please clarify: are you asking which DBMS (Database Management System) you should use that can be freely distributed with your commercial app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used PostgreSQL database for my own "semi-scientific" proof of concept project. Stored 50GB+ data. My experience is positive. You should be careful about partition scheme and indexing. It is free and supported by large online group.

Answer (score 2):

I think this question is still kind of vague. When you need to choose a database system, you may also need to consider some important factors, other than the input data size and freeware (budget).

1) You mentioned the purpose is scientific computation, do you need to support some complex and ad-hoc analytics/operations? For example, do you need to support time travel or multi-dimensional histogram generation? If so, you'd better choose a database specifically designed for scientific computing rather than a more general-purpose one, and **SciDB/MonetDB/RasDaMan** may be a good option.

2) You mentioned the data size, but what's the data type? Is it relational data (e.g., CSV),  array-based data (HDF5/NetCDF), or spatial data? One size does not fit all, and there are different types of databases specifically designed for different types of input data: relational/array/spatial... databases. Note that before you use any database, you have to load your data in the database, and the data loading maybe very painful if there is a mismatch between your input data type and the database type.

3) Performance may be a very crucial factor in your case, and you may also need to consider scalability if distributed computing is in your plan. For example, since scientific data is usually read-only or append-only, do you really need to guarantee ACID property during all the query execution? You may consider sacrificing ACID for more performance improvement. If so, SciDB may be way much better than SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can use actually almost anything, PostgreSQL, SQLite, and even Microsoft's SQL Server Compact or SQL Server.

It also depends on what is "a lot of data"/

Answer (score -2):

http://www.fakenamegenerator.com/ might help you out. Depends on the type of data you need.

Comment: What a different approach to the question than mine :)

Comment: I can warmly recommend fakenamegenerator. It even generates US and CA addresses in the right geografical distribution.

Comment: @Roland Bouman... Relevance to the question asked?

Comment: @Mevdiven this answer was relevant to the original question asked, which has since been altered to provide more information.

Comment: @Mevdiven, i do recognize my suggestion for fakenamegenerator but it was a reply to a post asking about a large *dataset* IIRC. I do not recognize this question at all. Maybe @glasnt is right and the question was changed, but if so it is now completely unrecognizable to me.